# How to Expand $\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^k$ to solve using L'Hopital's Rule

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do you expand $(\frac{k}{k+1})^k$ to get it into a form where I can evaluate the limit?

I know the answer is $\left(1 - \frac{1}{k+1}\right)^k$

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Write in the numerator $$k=k+1-1$$

Comment: Many thanks for this answer.

Comment: That's not a simplification, it's just a way to be able to expand binomially in case you need to, or to show the existence of some limit.

Comment: An excellent point.

Comment: $(\frac{k}{k+1})^k$ would look less ambiguous. The $\frac{k}{k+1}^k$ could easily be confused with $\frac{k^k}{k+1}$. What limit? As $k\to\infty$?

Comment: Thanks Mirko, it does indeed approach infinity but now it's figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that $\displaystyle\left( 1 + \frac a k\right)^k \to e^a$ as $k\to\infty$, then you can write
$$
\left( \frac k {k+1} \right)^k = \left( 1 + \frac{-1}{k+1} \right)^{k+1} \left( 1 + \frac{-1}{k+1} \right)^{-1} = \underbrace{ \left( 1 + \frac{-1} n \right)^n}_\text{This approaches $e^{-1}$.} \  \underbrace{ \left( 1 + \frac{-1} n \right)^{-1}. }_\text{This approaches 1.}
$$

If you must use L'Hopital's rule, you can write
$$
\left( \frac k {k+1} \right)^k = \exp\left( \log \left( \frac k {k+1} \right)^k \right) = \exp \left( k \log\left( \frac k {k+1} \right) \right) = \exp\left( \frac{\log\left( \frac k {k+1} \right)}{1/k} \right) \tag 1
$$
and then
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{\log\left( \frac k {k+1} \right)}{1/k} = \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1/(k+1)^2}{(-1/k^2)} = \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{-k^2}{(k+1)^2} = -1.
$$
Hence the limit of the expression in $(1)$ is $\exp(-1)$.